# How to center text inside a ListView?

Tags: listview, javafx

Is there any way to align text of elements to center inside a ListView in javafx?

I haven't found a method that does this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a css stylesheet to set the style alignment of `ListCell`s of a `ListView`. E.g. if the id `lv` is assigned to the `ListView`:

```css
#lv .list-cell {
    -fx-alignment: center;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to align a specific cell only?

Comment: @koulini You need a way write a selector for the `ListCell` you want to style. The only possibilities for selecting cells based on content or index are the `:empty`, `:filled`, `:odd` and `:even` pseudoclasses. To change this on a specific item that is not selected/focused, you need to write a custom `cellFactory` returning cells that update a style class/pseudoclass based on the content.

Answer (score 0):

try to load the font :

```
Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/direct/font_nam .ttf"), 20);
```

Answer (score -1):

Необходимо задать новую фабрику для формирования ячейки ListView. Для этого мы передаем новый объект Callback и  в метод setCellFactory, а у ячейки ListCell переопределяем метод call, где задаем правило формирования поступающих данных. Но на самом деле через стили css все делается проще, ответ с css выше был раскрыт.

```
    listViewOnExit.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> stringListView) {
            ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>(){
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    setText(item);
                }
            };
            cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            return cell;
        }
    });
```